# New line in html table

Tags: html, django

My model:

```
class Affiliation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

class Reg_Affiliation(models.Model):
    reg = ...
    affiliazione = models.ForeignKey(Affiliation, null=True, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='affiliation_conoscenza')
```

My `descrizione` field (for example):

```
descrizione = 'line1 <br> line2'
```

edit: added something about this field, see below /edit

I tried too:

```
descrizione = "line1 '<br>' line2"
descrizione = 'line1 "<br>" line2'
descrizione = 'line1 \n line2'
descrizione = 'line1 \r\n line2'
```

My template:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<table class="table table-striped table table-bordered table table-hover table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {% for aff in lista %}
      <tr>
        <td>
            <b>{{ aff.affiliazione }}</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ aff.affiliazione.descrizione }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect:

```
line1

line2
```

in the same field of my table, instead I obtain:

```
line1 <br> line2
```

My `views`:

```
@login_required
def affiliation_list(request):
    lista_a=[]
    for a in Affiliation.objects.all():
        ra=Reg_Affiliation(affiliazione=a, 
                conoscenza=c, 
                rapporto=r)
            lista_a.append(ra)
        context_dict['lista'] = lista_a
    return render(request, 'core/affiliation_list.html', context_dict)
```

I'm using bootstrap, firefox, windows7

Thank you for your help

edit:

maybe it make difference how I add the `descrizione` field, so:

My `populate` script:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sitoposs.settings')

import django
django.setup()

def populate():

    affiliation1 = add_affiliation('name affiliation1', '''long line1 <br> long line2''')
    affiliation2 = 
    ...

def add_affiliation(name, descrizione):
    a = Affiliation.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    a.descrizione=descrizione
    a.save()
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    populate()
```

In my database I read

```
long line1 <br> long line2
```

In source page (on the browser right click on the page, view source page or something like that, I don't use english version) I read:
    long line1 <br> long line2

In my populate script I tried also:

```
affiliation1 = add_affiliation('name affiliation1', 'long line1 and <br> long line2 in the same line, so unreadable')
```

Comment: This seems more like a Django question than an HTML question.. Adding tags and re-wording parts of your post might attract more answers. Also, the relevant `views.py` will also provide insight.

Comment: Added TAG and views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `descrizione = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)` instead of  `descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)`

and

use `{% autoescape off %}{{ aff.affiliazione.descrizione }}{% endautoescape %}` instead of `{{ aff.affiliazione.descrizione }}`

Generally django escape all html tag and render as raw text, to render actual html you can also use `{{ aff.affiliazione.descrizione|safe }}`

Comment: Sorry, doesn't change nothing

Comment: @fabio now take a look